# Custom Google Translate model API to Postman

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner, google-translation-api, google-cloud-translate

I have my custom Google Cloud translate model with API, and i want to deploy it at Postman. What do json file i must have for it to add in my collections and how do I need fill it?
Thanks!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W93y4.png)
I read documentation and some examples at Postman, but it didn't help me.